# Help with contextual filter and entity reference fields

Tags: 8, entities, views

I have a content type with an entity reference field that allows users to assign multiple other nodes to be referenced from the current node.

I am trying to create a view that will list the related nodes for the current page.

What Relationship/s and contextual filters must be set to achieve such a thing?

I have read a number of other posts asking similar questions, though most seem to be in reference to Drupal 7 and their suggestions either do not work, or appear to not exist in Drupal 8.

I can get a list which shows all the other nodes that reference the current node by setting a contextual filter to: `Content:field_related_pages` and setting the default value to `Content ID from URL` this, however, is the exact opposite of what I want...

I have tried creating a relationship based on the Entity Reference field, however there are two options I can see:

- `Content referenced from field_related_pages`
- `Content using field_related_pages`

I have also tried using a contextual filter of: `Content: ID` with the default value set to `Content ID from URL`

I feel like I have attempted every conceivable combination of the above and none seems to work. Can someone please put me out of my misery and incompetence and please how to get a contextual filter to show a list of nodes related to the current via a entity reference field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had the following selected under the "more" tab in the contextual filter:

`Exclude If selected, the numbers entered for the filter will be excluded rather than limiting the view.`

Which lead to all kinds of odd behaviour...

If it is of use to anyone else, the correct answer appears to be:

- `Content using field_related_pages` with the relationship required.
- The contextual filter set to Content: ID with  with the ```default value set to Content ID from URL`` and
- Relationship dropdown set to the `field_related_pages`